# Block of jQuery causes page not to render

Tags: jquery, dom

I am trying to display a list of YouTube videos from a playlist onto my page.  I can get the videos to display just fine.  I'm attempting to add "sorting" by Name or Date of the video, but when I add the code, the page doesn't render the videos at all.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="hg-portfolio-sortable">
<div id="sorting" class="fixclear"> <span class="sortTitle">Sort By: </span>

    <ul id="sortBy" class="option-set " data-option-key="sortBy" data-default="">
        <li><a href="#sortBy=name" data-option-value="name">Name</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#sortBy=date" data-option-value="date">Date</a>
        </li>
    </ul> <span class="sortTitle">Direction: </span>

    <ul id="sort-direction" class="option-set " data-option-key="sortAscending">
        <li><a href="#sortAscending=true" data-option-value="true">ASC</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#sortAscending=false" data-option-value="false">DESC</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<ul id="portfolio-nav" class="fixclear">
    <li class="current"><a href="#" data-filter="*">All</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".websites">Websites</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".print">Print</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".logo">Logo</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="clear"></div>
<ul id="thumbs"></ul>
```

and here's the script in the `$(window).load(function())`:

```
    //SORTING CODE
// settings
var sortBy = 'date',
    sortAscending = true,
    theFilter = ''; // DEFAULT FILTERING CATEGORY 

$('#sortBy li a').each(function (index, element) {
    var $t = $(this);
    if ($t.attr('data-option-value') == sortBy) $t.addClass('selected');
});
$('#sort-direction li a').each(function (index, element) {
    var $t = $(this);
    if ($t.attr('data-option-value') == sortAscending.toString()) $t.addClass('selected');
});
$('#portfolio-nav li a').each(function (index, element) {
    var $t = $(this),
        tpar = $t.parent();
    if ($t.attr('data-filter') == theFilter) {
        $('#portfolio-nav li a').parent().removeClass('current');
        tpar.addClass('current');
    }
});


if ($("ul#thumbs").length > 0) {
    var $container = $("ul#thumbs");
    $container.isotope({
        itemSelector: ".item",
        animationEngine: "jquery",
        animationOptions: {
            duration: 250,
            easing: "easeOutExpo",
            queue: false
        },
        filter: theFilter,
        sortAscending: sortAscending,
        getSortData: {
            name: function ($elem) {
                return $elem.find("span.name").text();
            },
            date: function ($elem) {
                return $elem.attr("data-date");
            }
        },
        sortBy: sortBy
    });
}
//END SORTING CODE

//VIDEO CODE
var playListURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/SP8CE46F72D4FE9E45?v=2&alt=json&max-results=50&callback=?';
var videoURL = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=';
$.getJSON(playListURL, function (data) {
    var list_data = "";
    var column_count = -1; // -1;
    var end_li = "</li>";
    var begin_div = "<div class='inner-item'>";
    var end_div = "</div>";
    var html_data = "";

    $.each(data.feed.entry, function (i, item) {
        column_count = column_count + 1;
        var feedTitle = item.title.$t;
        var feedURL = item.link[1].href;
        var videoDate = item.published.$t;
        var fragments = feedURL.split("/");
        var videoID = fragments[fragments.length - 2];
        var description = ""; item.description; //RETURNS Undefined.
        var url = videoURL + videoID;
        var thumb = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + videoID + "/default.jpg";
        var begin_li = "<li class='item websites ###' data-date='" + videoDate + "'>";
        var even_odd = "even";
        var begin_h4 = "<h4 class='title'>";
        var end_h4 = "</h4>";

        if (column_count % 2) even_odd = "odd";

        begin_li = begin_li.replace("###", even_odd);

        html_data += begin_li + begin_div +
            '<a data-rel="prettyPhoto[iframes]" class="hoverLink" href="' + url + '">' +
            '<img src="' + thumb + '" alt="' + feedTitle + '" />' +
            '</a>' + begin_h4 +
            '<a href="' + url + '" target="_blank"><span class="name">' + feedTitle + '</span></a>' + end_h4 +
            '<span class="moduleDesc">' +
            '<p>' + description + '</p>' +
            '</span>' +
            '<div class="clear"></div>' + end_div + end_li;
    });
    $(html_data).appendTo("#thumbs");

});
```

In short, the getJSON creates the html for each video and appends it to the `<ul id="thumbs">` tag.  Again, this is working but when I added my "Sorting" code, the page doesn't render at all now.  Any ideas why?  Also, I tried to get the "Description" from the feed but `item.description` returns undefined, yet there is a description for all these videos? And I am also trying to figure out why it's displaying them from "Right to Left".  If you take the fiddle below and append `/show` to the end, you'll see what I'm talking about.  Why wouldn't this append them "Left to Right" as expected?

Here's a fiddle to put it all together: [*UPDATED* Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/robertfah/guMQa/22/) and I am using jQuery 1.8.2. (even though the fiddle says 1.8.3).

**UPDATE**

Sorry for the confusion with jsFiddle...I didn't know after each time I press "Update", I also need to supply that url to everyone (I figured it would have updated the old urls).  At any rate, the latest one is now in the link.  With the way the fiddle currently sits (Version # 22), the issues I am having are:

1.) No Videos are being displayed.  If you comment out everything above this line `var playListURL=...` then you will see that you get Videos....but of course, no sorting.
2.) Still can't get `description` from each video (`item.description` returns undefined)
3.) If you comment out the code from #1, and then append `/show` to the end of the URL, you will see the rendered HTML, videos and all (no sorting) but scroll down and you will see they are aligned to the right, not to the left.

Comment: From the console: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'easeOutExpo'

Comment: I added the js to the fiddle which has this in it (plugins.js).

Comment: Did you update the fiddle link? I can't see it loaded and that same error is still occurring.

Comment: Ugh....sorry, it's one of those days....I just clicked Update.

Comment: Not too familiar with jsFiddle but didn't know if I had to supply the new url after I hit update...here it is just in case: http://jsfiddle.net/robertfah/guMQa/22/

Comment: It'll not update in the question, you have to edit it. But http://jsfiddle.net/robertfah/guMQa/18/ seems to work. At least the page is rendered

Comment: @Robert in the new Fiddle nothing is showing unlike the old one. Also what are you trying to do as I am having a hard time understanding exactly what is going on besides the object error. Also some CSS flaws ;)

Comment: Correct, but if you uncomment the JavaScript at the top, you won't see the videos anymore.

Comment: Oh ok I gotcha also if you want this worked for me you can try it out for the description  `var descript = entry.media$group.media$description.$t`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/guMQa/23/  for description :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why wouldn't this append them "Left to Right" as expected?

Append means add to the end of. You may need [`.prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)

The description was quite easy to find using a `console.log(data)`:
[image]

```
item.media$group.media$description.$t
```

The reason why your thumbnails aren't showing is probably due to an animation, which causes the elements to get the CSS properties `overflow: hidden` and `height: 0`, which basically makes the element invisible.

[image]

Comment: I was wondering why the elements were showing up in the console but not on the page.  I'm still new to using the console and such but this answers my main question as to why the vidz weren't showing up.  I've removed that animation for now.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

For your description problem

http://jsfiddle.net/guMQa/23/

We have to use this JS to grab that information

```
var description =  item.media$group.media$description.$t;
```

Hope that helped you with that. I will look into the rest and update as I go

Is this what you wanted?

http://jsfiddle.net/guMQa/24/

Comment: This gets the description, just as expected.  I see that you removed the `easing` code, as it was doing just was DJDavid98 said above, making the element invisible.  Thanks a bunch for this!

Comment: Does the code work like you want or does it need more. Easier to see on JSBIN here http://jsbin.com/iqulol/1

Comment: I think the 'Date' "sort" functions isn't working.  If you click 'Name', they sort, but nothing happens if you click 'Date'.

Comment: Ok i'll look into you do realize what I fixed though correct?

Comment: Well since you marked the answer by david as answered I'm done as you are stating the question needs no more assistance